# Amazon EC2 default instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, terminate

How can I terminate default EC2 instance. I can delete the default instance but automatically it is getting created after some time

Comment: Is there an Autoscaling Group doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it part of a auto scaling group? Auto scaling groups has a parameter called MinSize. This is the minimum size of the group.

Type: Integer
Required: Yes

If the number of instance fails below MinSize it'll automatically create one.

Also make sure there are no automated jobs that are creating instances using AWS CLI.